# Dynamic Django Bootstrap accordion inside for loop not loading

Tags: django, for-loop, templates, bootstrap-4, accordion

I've been working on an online portfolio and have been using the Django framework to do so. For a *projects* tab, I pass in an object (**projects**) containing the details of all my projects and try to show them in an accordion through a for loop in a dynamic template. But the tabs do not collapse upon clicking them (like they should). I have no idea why.

````
{% block content %}
<h1>Projects</h1>
<div class="accordion accordion-md" id="projectsAccordion" 
    role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    {% for project in projects %}    
        <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="{{ project.name }}heading">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse"  data-parent="#projectsAccordion"
                        href="#{{ project.id }}" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-controls="{{ project.name }}">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            {{ project.name }}
                        </h5>
                    </a>
                </div> <!-- card header -->

                <div id="{{ project.id }}" class="collapse" role="tabpanel"
                    aria-labelledby="{{ project.name }}heading" data-parent="#projectsAccordion">
                    <div class="card-block px-3 my-2">
                        <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
                        <p>Timeframe: {{project.start_date}} - {{project.end_date}}</p>

                        {% if project.motivation %}
                            <p>Motivation: {{ project.motivation }}</p>
                        {% endif %}

                        <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                            {% for tech in project.technologies.all %}
                                <li class="list-inline-item"><p>{{ tech.name }}</p></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>    

                        <button type="button" href="{{ project.link }}" target="_blank"
                            class="btn btn-primary align-text-top project-link">
                            Code
                        </button>

                    </div> <!-- card body -->
                </div> <!-- collapse -->
        </div><!-- card -->
    {% endfor %}
</div> <!-- accordion -->
{% endblock %}```
````